# Passing Variable Between C# And Python (IronPython?)

Tags: c#, python, .net

I am trying to pass a variable from a C# application, which is being used as an API connection.

Essentially Outsystems produces a signal, which the C# applications picks up. I then want to pass this (single integer) variable onto my python code (labelled msg in my code below), so that it can run the function using it.

I have researched, and it looks like ironpython has a solution:

```
{
    ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
    ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);
    ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("C:\\Scripts\\12\\Testpy\\Testpy\\Testpy.py");
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
    List<String> argv = new List<String>();
    //Do some stuff and fill argv
    argv.Add(msg);
    engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);
    source.Execute(scope);
}
```

However, it seems to do nothing (no error, just stops executing) when it gets the the source.Execute(scope) side.

I'd imagine (?) it's because my python code isn't set up to receive variables yet. However, this is the part that I am unsure on how to write.

I - unfortunately - have little experience in passing values into python scripts, but have set up the following simple example (that is python script to python script) that seems to be working okay:

pyA

```
import pyB

pyB.some_func(2)
```

pyB

```
def some_func(a):
    print(a)

some_func()
```

Alternatively, if anyone can recommend another non-Iron Python way, that would also be amazing!

Thanks in advance!! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From code link in this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1VWGdHRkHs

```
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = @"C:\PythonInstall\python.exe";

    // 2) Provide script and arguments
    var script = @"C:\AllTech\Code\DaysBetweenDates.py";
    var start = "2019-1-1";
    var end = "2019-1-22";

    psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{start}\" \"{end}\"";

    // 3) Process configuration
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

    // 4) Execute process and get output
    var errors = "";
    var results = "";

    using(var process = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }

    // 5) Display output
    Console.WriteLine("ERRORS:");
    Console.WriteLine(errors);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Results:");
    Console.WriteLine(results);
```